# Clean unicode before adding to Dictionary

Tags: python, regex, xpath

When parsing a page, I am pulling:

```
'label_value': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tabc123\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']}
```

My goal is to just pull the relevant "abc123" from that xpath when it writes to the CSV. Currently, due to the "\n\t" in the string, it isn't writing anything. Looking around, I found several methods how to accomplish this, but I have been unable to properly place it within my own code and have it execute properly.

I've been playing with regex and .translate() to remove the instances of \n\t and clean up the code to cleanly add it to a csv. I didn't have much success with regex since these are pullings as lists, so I ceded to using .translate().

Below, I added my code for defining the xpaths and the actual page parsing. There is a step between that kicks off the spider and parses an initial page, but I didn't find that relevant to this question so omitted it from the code.

Of the sections below, where would I want to add this code? Would it be when I define the label_value's xpath, in the initial spider, or when I'm actually extracting it to my ResultsDict?

```
label_value = './/*[@class="lorem-ipsum"]
```

instead use...

```
label_value = './/*[@class="lorem-ipsum"].translate(None, '\t\n ')
```

or...

```
def parsepage(self, response)
    time.sleep(2)
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    selectable_page = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
    ResultsDict = scraperpageitems()
    ResultsDict['label_value'] = selectable_page.xpath(label_value).extract()
```

instead use...

```
    ResultsDict['label_value'] = selectable_page.xpath(label_value).extract().translate(None, '\t\n ')
```

Comment: Could you clarify whether `\n` or `\t` can occur within the wanted result string. i.e. can a string look like this: `\n\t\t\tabc\n\t123\n\t\t\t\t`, and if so what is the intended behavior?

Comment: I'd like to have it as clean as possible, so just 'abc123', with no outlying text.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Can there be line breaks in the desired text? For example, the text could be from a multi-line text box, and it may be desirable to keep the formatting the user entered and only strip surrounding tabs and new-lines before and after the user input.

Comment: That wasn't your question, but no, these are all from single lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you simply looking for `strip()` ?
Consider this example (see it [**working on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/CuRgKP))

```
label_value = '''


                                abc123


'''
print(label_value)
print(label_value.strip())
```

---

For the records, this did the trick:

```
[x.strip() for x in selectable_page.xpath(label_value).extract()]
```

Comment: where would the .strip() fall in the code? I've attempted it in several areas but they all come back with the extra spaces and \n\t still.


`selectable_page.xpath(label_value.strip()).extract()

selectable_page.xpath(label_value).strip().extract()`

Comment: `selectable_page.xpath(label_value).extract().strip()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

This is the main issue I've been running into with a lot of these. I'm wondering if I need to iterate through the strip sooner in the code...

Comment: is this `scrapy` ? You could use `extract_first()` instead or use a list comprehension.

Comment: List comprehension: `[x.strip() for x in selectable_page.xpath(label_value).extract()]`

Comment: Yessir, it is 'scrapy'

Here is a copy/paste of the xpath selected on the site...
`<td> abc123 </td>`

and what I see as it's going through terminal...
`'label_value': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tabc123\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']`

I'm pulling several different 'label_values' into one column, so it must be due to the fact it is putting them into a dictionary (e.g. 'label_value1': [u'value'], 'label_value2': [u'value'], etc)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to trim the whitespaces.

Something like do a global
Find `^\s+|\s+$`
and replace with nothing.

You mentioned stripping Unicode.
If you want to strip Unicode as well, use `^\s+|[\x{100}-\x{10ffff}]+|\s+$`
Not sure what Python uses for *Unicode* in classes, use whatever form
they make available `\uXXXX` or `\UXXXXXX` and braces `{}` as needed.

Comment: The best way would be to use `strip()` :)

Comment: Sure as long as it strips whitespace.

Comment: Citing from the official [**`strip()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) doc: `If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed.`

Comment: So they must use a regex or something.

Answer (score 0):

I credit @Martjin for this solution... (I take credit for the comment)

```
#UNICODE is a pain in my ass! below is a function to strip-out and replace with a space.
def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in text])
```